# Adding custom tag stops rendering of the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
class TodoList extends Component {

     List = props => (
  <ul>
    {
      props.items.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)
    }
  </ul>
);

    state = {
      term: '',
      items: []
    };
    onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({term: event.target.value});
  }
onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      term: '',
      items: [...this.state.items, this.state.term]
    });
  }
    handleClick=()=>{
   this.setState(({count})=>({
       count: count+1
   }));
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <h2>
                        Todo List
                    </h2>
                    <form className="App" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
       <input value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onChange} />
       <button>Submit</button>
   </form>
<List items={this.state.items}/>

                </div>
                <style>{`
                    .is-done {
                        text-decoration: line-through;
                    }
                `}</style>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The above code renders fine if I remove the tag below the form tag `<List items={this.state.items}/>` Not sure what could be the reason for this. I am making a simple 
todo list here. It shows the `submit` button along with input text box and the heading
`Todo List` . But with that last tag <List added it doesn't show anything and there is a blank page

Comment: Move the `List` component outside of the `TodoList` class.

Comment: Do you mean both the <List tag and the `List = props ` or only one of them? If I move it out, then do I wrap them into a different class

Comment: Only the `List = props` one. There is no need to wrap it in another class. React components can be defined as functions too.

Answer (score 0):

The advice to move it outside the class is fine, and you SHOULD do it, but you should also understand why it didn't work.

The smallest fix you could do, and it WOULD work that way would be to change

```
<List items={this.state.items}/>
```

to

```
<this.List items={this.state.items}/>
```

Why? Because the functional component is created inside the class, and thus when React translates JSX code into JS functions - inside the class it is a method belonging to the class (and we know these should be called with this).

If you take it outside the class, then you don't need this, because it is in the same scope as the class definition.